# Error while Installing ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.3.4

I am following [this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-overview.html#install-prereq-java-ubuntu) doc page for installing ElasticSearch. This requires Java so again I followed [this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-overview.html#install-prereq-java-ubuntu) doc page to install Java.

The commands are,

```
add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java
apt-get -y update
apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer
```

The 3rd command threw bellow error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package oracle-java8-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate
```

After some search I found out from [here](https://www.rajivlodha.com/oracle-java-is-no-longer-free/) that the Java is no longer free.

**Question**: Should I purchase Java License if I want to use/install ElasticSearch?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55920389/e-package-oracle-java8-installer-has-no-installation-candidate

Comment: @SavanPatel. Thank you. But my question is different. I want to use ElasticSearch/Java in Production . _Oracle Java is Free for personal and development use, but you need to have an active subscription (paid) to continue using Oracle Java for commercial purpose_

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this for Ubuntu 20.04

```
sudo apt-cache search openjdk
sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jdk
java -version
sudo gedit /etc/environment
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
echo $JAVA_HOME
sudo curl -fsSL https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add - (OK)
sudo echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list  
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elasticsearch
sudo gedit /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

cluster.name: my-application
node.name: magentocom
network.publish_host: localhost
discovery.seed_hosts: []
network.host: 127.0.0.1
http.port: 9200
cluster.initial_master_nodes: 127.0.0.1

sudo journalctl -xe

sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
sudo systemctl status elasticsearch
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200'
curl http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
http://localhost:9200/
```

Hope this solves your issue !!!

Answer (score 0):

Download **elasticsearch** from this URL https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch

Then unzip it in windows localhost htdocs folder
please rename the folder to **elasticsearch**

After that open

> htdocs\elasticsearch\bin

and in that find **elasticsearch.bat** file
Right-click on that file and click *Run as administrator*.

Now the command window will open and elasticsearch is now working
Don't close it while you are using all your command you mentioned in other command prompts.